# Parking Light on 1990 Volvo 240 Not Working,

Tags: electrical, volvo

The driver's side parking light on my 1991 Volvo 240 is not working. Bulb is ok.
Turn signal and head lights working fine.

Mechanic says it is most likely a corroded wire inside an "assembly" or "harness" in the engine compartment?

- What would I need to do or have replaced?
- How expensive could it be?

There are some other issues with this car, so it might not be worth it.

Comment: Too many possibilities to answer concisely, voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely place for corrosion to occur is at the bulb socket. Take the light bulb assemble apart and inspect the socket and the wires going to it.
Have a look [here](http://new.volvocars.com/ownersdocs/1992/1992_240/92240_088.htm), this bulb should be "push and twist" to remove.